# Selecting one value from loop and transferring out of subroutine to main program (Fortran)

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I am new to programming in Fortran. I would be very grateful for any help on this problem. I need to transfer a value from a do loop out of the subroutine where the looping takes place, into the main program.. Something like this:

```
program wet

implicit none

real(8) sulstar, u1, u2, theta1, theta2, q1, q2, tol
real(8) sblstar, surstar, sbrstar
open(3,file="theta1.txt",status="unknown")


tol=1

call ra1(sulstar,sblstar)

u1=sulstar

q1=(u1)**3

write(3,*) q1, u1

end 

subroutine ra1(ulstar,blstar)
! Purpose: To calculate variables across rarefaction1 before the shock

implicit none

real(8) h(51), u(51), b(51), x(51), l(51), inibl, inihl, iniul
real(8) delta, ulstar,blstar
integer i, itermax, t_start


t_start=1
itermax=51
delta=0.01
inihl=1
iniul=0
inibl=0

open(unit=1,file="rare1.txt",status="unknown")
  do 10 i=2, itermax

  h(i)=inihl-(i-1)*delta

  u(1)=iniul
  h(1)=inihl
  l(1)=u(1)-sqrt(h(1))

  u(i)=u(i-1)+((lambda1(i-1)-u(i-1))/h(i-1))*(h(i)-h(i-1))

  lambda1(i)=u(i)-sqrt(h(i))
  b(1)=inibl

  b(i)=b(i-1)+(((lambda1(i-1)-u(i-1))**2)/(h(i))-1)*(h(i)-h(i-1))


  x(1)=l(1)*t_start
  x(i)=l(i)*t_start

write(1,*) x(i), h(i), u(i), b(i) 


u(51)=ulstar
b(51)=blstar

10 continue
return

end
```

I found out that whenever I try to select the 51st value of U, the 51st value gets distorted, meaning that the value turns out to be zero or a very small number instead of the correct u value when u(51)=ulstar does not appear in the subroutine.
Could someone advice me on how I can select the last value of u and pass it to main program?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I've rolled this back: if you want to ask a new question, please do so as a new question rather than as an edit to a previously answered one.

Answer (score 0):

Place your procedures into a module and use that module so that the compiler can check consistency of arguments in the call and in the procedure.  It looks to me that you have some undeclared  variables.    e.g., where are `lambda1` and `h` declared?

```
module MyStuff

contains

subroutine ra1(ulstar,blstar)
! Purpose: To calculate variables across rarefaction1 before the shock

implicit none

real(8) h(51), u(51), b(51), x(51), l(51), inibl, inihl, iniul
real(8) delta, ulstar,blstar
integer i, itermax, t_start


t_start=1
itermax=51
delta=0.01
inihl=1
iniul=0
inibl=0

open(unit=1,file="rare1.txt",status="unknown")
  do 10 i=2, itermax

  h(i)=inihl-(i-1)*delta

  u(1)=iniul
  h(1)=inihl
  l(1)=u(1)-sqrt(h(1))

  u(i)=u(i-1)+((lambda1(i-1)-u(i-1))/h(i-1))*(h(i)-h(i-1))

  lambda1(i)=u(i)-sqrt(h(i))
  b(1)=inibl

  b(i)=b(i-1)+(((lambda1(i-1)-u(i-1))**2)/(h(i))-1)*(h(i)-h(i-1))


  x(1)=l(1)*t_start
  x(i)=l(i)*t_start

write(1,*) x(i), h(i), u(i), b(i)


u(51)=ulstar
b(51)=blstar

10 continue
return

end subroutine ra1

end module MyStuff


program wet

use MyStuff

implicit none

real(8) sulstar, u1, u2, theta1, theta2, q1, q2, tol
real(8) sblstar, surstar, sbrstar
open(3,file="theta1.txt",status="unknown")


tol=1

call ra1(sulstar,sblstar)

u1=sulstar

q1=(u1)**3

write(3,*) q1, u1

end program wet
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, what I wanted to do was transfer the 51st value in u(i) to the main program. I added "ulstar" and "blstar" next to write(1,*) but it did not extract the final value of u(i). It brought out 6.9E-310 for u(51) and 0.0 for b(51) instead of 0.57 and -6.8E-03 respectively. Subsequently, the values transferred to main program are also incorrect.

Comment: What compiler are you using?   Are you getting error messages when you compile this code?  I am.   So how are you getting execution results?  Or have you not shown 100% of the code?  You have `u(51)=ulstar` but where does `ulstar` get assigned a value?  Not from `sulstar`, which isn't assigned either.

Comment: Thank you M.S.B. for your comments. Yes, I have not shown 100% of my original code. I can assure you that I have declared all the variables being used in this program. I was expecting that ulstar will get the value of 51st row in u(i) (because u(51)=ulstar). Did I make a mistake thinking this is possible?

Comment: Also, after getting the value from ulstar, it is transferred to sulstar in the main program by using call command. This is how I pictured it.

Comment: *I was expecting that ulstar will get the value of 51st row in u(i) (because u(51)=ulstar)* No,you've got that the wrong way round, your code assigns the value of `ulstar` to `u(51)`.  Since `ulstar` does not seem to be given a value anywhere (it doesn't appear on the lhs of any assignments nor acquire a value in any other way that I can see) `u(51)` will get the value of whatever junk is in the memory locations labelled `ulstar` when the code executes.